# How to move files in Azure Data Lake Store with Powershell -recursive?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

I am trying to figure out a way to move files from one folder to another on ADLS gen1, without knowing the exact file name.

I wanted to try with Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem and Move-AzDataLakeStoreItem with using -recursive, but this is not supported in AZ for some reason.

I was trying this

```
Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account "my_acc" -Path "/Training/TestCopy/Source/" |
Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} -OutVariable File | 
Move-AzDataLakeStoreItem -Account "my_acc" -Destination "/Training/TestCopy/Target/$File" -WhatIf
```

But it only gives:
What if: Performing the operation "Move" on target "/Training/TestCopy/Target".

What I would expect is to get files from "/Training/TestCopy/Source/" to "/Training/TestCopy/Target/"

I'm not that good in all that stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to move the files from one folder to another folder. If so, you use the command

```
# Path: Specify the Data Lake Store path of the item to move
#Destination: Specify the Data Lake Store path to which to move the item
Move-AzDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "ContosoADL" -Path "/Original/Path/File.txt" -Destination "/New/Path/RenamedFile.txt"
```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datalakestore/move-azdatalakestoreitem?view=azps-2.8.0.

```
Connect-AzAccount

$account = Get-AzDataLakeStoreAccount -ResourceGroupName asS -Name testadls02

$sourcePath="/test"
#get the files in the source folder
$files =Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account $account.Name -Path $sourcePath

$targetPath ="/test1"

Foreach($file in $files){

  $name = $file.Name

  Move-AzDataLakeStoreItem -Account $account.Name -Path $file.Path -Destination "$targetPath/$name"
}
Write-Host "the file in sourcePath folder"
Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account $account.Name -Path $sourcePath
Write-Host "-----------------------"
Write-Host "the file in targetPath folder"
Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account $account.Name -Path $targetPath
```

[image]